# How "pickle" works on py-mel?

Tags: python, pickle, maya, pymel

I'm trying to store some variables with pickle using python on Maya, but I'm having some problem.
The error that shows up is:

> # Error: IOError: file  -maya console-  line 6: 13 #

that's what I've tried:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import pickle

names =["Marcus","Mario","Stefan"]

pickle.dump(names, open("names.dat","wb"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code, the main issue being that the `open` command doesn't know how to resolve `"names.dat"` to a proper path. Here's some other issues:

1. You should pass a full path in the `open` function. Something like `"path/to/my/directory/names.dat"`
2. You are using `"wb"`, but that is to write as binary. The problem is the data you're passing isn't binary! Instead you can use `pickle.dumps(names, True)` to serialize the data as binary.
3. You can actually use `cPickle` instead of `pickle`. Just replace everything to `cPickle` and it should work the exact same way. The difference being that `cPickle` processes in C instead of Python, so it calculates much faster.
4. When you create a new `open` object, you should clean up after yourself by calling its close method. What you can do instead is use it with `with`, so that it automatically closes when it's finished.

Putting all of these together, you should get this instead:

```
import cPickle

names = ["Marcus", "Mario", "Stefan"]

with open("path/to/my/directory/names.dat", "wb") as f:
    f.write(cPickle.dumps(names, True))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, now it runs like a charm!

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to accept this answer if you feel like your question has been resolved.